# Flask app deployed on heroku using gunicorn state changed from starting to crashed

Tags: flask, heroku, deployment, gunicorn

I would like to deploy the back-end of my app on heroku, so it would communicate with the front (also deployed on heroku). However I am facing an issue when I am trying to use it.

My source code is on this github : https://github.com/Barth2501/mylittlecellar-back

I am using flask on the port 8000, so I have build the Procfile

```
web: gunicorn web:app
```

and my resuirements.txt also contain gunicorn:

```
aniso8601==8.0.0
astroid==2.3.3
attrs==19.3.0
Automat==20.2.0
certifi==2019.11.28
cffi==1.14.0
chardet==3.0.4
click==7.1.1
constantly==15.1.0
crochet==1.12.0
cryptography==2.8
cssselect==1.1.0
Flask==1.1.1
Flask-Cors==3.0.8
Flask-JWT-Extended==3.24.1
Flask-RESTful==0.3.8
gunicorn==20.0.4
hyperlink==19.0.0
idna==2.9
incremental==17.5.0
isort==4.3.21
itsdangerous==1.1.0
Jinja2==2.11.1
lazy-object-proxy==1.4.3
lxml==4.5.0
MarkupSafe==1.1.1
mccabe==0.6.1
nltk==3.4.5
numpy==1.18.2
pandas==1.0.3
parsel==1.5.2
peewee==3.13.1
Protego==0.1.16
psycopg2==2.8.4
pyasn1==0.4.8
pyasn1-modules==0.2.8
pycparser==2.20
PyDispatcher==2.0.5
PyHamcrest==2.0.2
PyJWT==1.7.1
pylint==2.4.4
pyOpenSSL==19.1.0
python-dateutil==2.8.1
python-dotenv==0.12.0
pytz==2019.3
queuelib==1.5.0
requests==2.23.0
Scrapy==2.0.1
service-identity==18.1.0
six==1.14.0
Twisted==20.3.0
typed-ast==1.4.1
Unidecode==1.1.1
urllib3==1.25.8
w3lib==1.21.0
Werkzeug==1.0.0
wrapt==1.11.2
zope.interface==5.0.0
```

When I am trying to deploy it on heroku, the builds is doing fine, but when I am looking at my logs, here is what I have:

```
2020-04-18T13:18:04.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user barthelemy.lancelot@student.ecp.fr
2020-04-18T13:19:36.297211+00:00 app[api]: Deploy 99e33c23 by user barthelemy.lancelot@student.ecp.fr
2020-04-18T13:19:36.297211+00:00 app[api]: Release v10 created by user barthelemy.lancelot@student.ecp.fr
2020-04-18T13:19:37.715963+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2020-04-18T13:19:46.367291+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-04-18 13:19:46 +0000] [4] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.0.4
2020-04-18T13:19:46.368119+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-04-18 13:19:46 +0000] [4] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:8000 (4)
2020-04-18T13:19:46.368299+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-04-18 13:19:46 +0000] [4] [INFO] Using worker: sync
2020-04-18T13:19:46.374529+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-04-18 13:19:46 +0000] [10] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 10
2020-04-18T13:19:46.401317+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-04-18 13:19:46 +0000] [11] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 11
2020-04-18T13:19:54.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2020-04-18T13:20:44.417727+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
```

So I really don't know where to look to solve this crash, could anyone help me on this?

Thank you so much

Comment: I think that the naming of the file ```web.py``` may have a issue. Try changing it.

Comment: also you should use the PORT environment vairble to show your web app to the port that heroku assigns it . PORT 8080 WOULDN'T WORK

Comment: I get "state changed from starting to up" and that it listens on 0.0.0.0:9559 but when I try to connect my frontend to <app-name>.herokuapp.com:9559 it doesn't find anything. Have I done somehting wrong?

Comment: Moreover, after releaseing the heroku app, when I do heroku open -a <app-name> I get 404 not found. Is it because I am using this app as a restful API?

Comment: Btw <app-name> us the name of your app